# Inno Setup - File in use, disallow skip/cancel

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have configured "Inno Setup" as needed, but there is one point which I'm not able to modify.

We have an application which is installed on a network folder on the customers server. Basically updating the files works as expected.

If some client on the network, someone which has not initiated the update, has opened the application I'm receiving an messagebox/errorbox "delete file failed.... file is in use by another process" - including 3 buttons "try again", "skip this files (not recommended)", "cancel installation". I have attached an example picture (found on the internet, but the same message).

[image: File in use]

There you can see the 3 buttons. I want to disable "skip this file" and "cancel installation". The user should have the ability to hit "try again" - they should get stucked until all client have closed their application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can alter that message box.

There are two alternatives:

- You can delete the target file using your own code before installing the new version, not allowing to proceed until the file is gone.

  ```pascal
  [Files]
  Source: "Source: "C:\SampleApplicationData\*"; DestDir: "{app}\SampleApp"; \
      Flags: recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; BeforeInstall: ForcedDelete

  [Code]

  procedure ForcedDelete;
  var
    FileName: string;
    Deleted: Boolean;
  begin
    FileName := ExpandConstant(CurrentFileName);
    repeat
      if not FileExists(FileName) then
      begin
        Log(Format('File %s does not exist', [FileName]));
        Deleted := True;
      end
        else
      if DeleteFile(FileName) then
      begin
        Log(Format('File %s was deleted', [FileName]));
        Deleted := True;
      end
        else
      begin
        MsgBox(Format('Error deleting %s.', [FileName]), mbError, MB_OK);
        Deleted := False;
      end;
    until Deleted;
  end;
  ```

  Though I still believe the code should at least allow an abort.
- Or use [`restartreplace` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=restartreplace).

Comment: If you delete the files using your own code, and any file is in use, you can prompt for retry without the cancel/skip options. Try way, the user will have to keep trying until the file gets deleted eventually. Then the installation will proceed without any issues, as it will be installing into an empty folder. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: See my updated answer (it's bit different/better/easier solution that what I have proposed initially).

Comment: I have tested your code successfully on my local computer, but now I have tried it on our test environment. Now I'm getting a new error message **An error occurred while trying to rename a file in the destination directory: MoveFile failed; code183. A file cannot be created if it already exists**. I'm getting a popup like in the first post (try again, skip, cancel) Your code for deleting the file has finished without any error, and the file doesn't exist anymore on the networkfolder. I think it is locked somewhere in background because of the opened application on the second client.

Comment: So the `DeleteFile` succeeds, yet the file still exists? Did you check if the file is indeed still there, while the error is showing? + Replace `Log(Format('File %s was deleted', [FileName]));` with `Log(Format('File %s was deleted - exists? %d', [FileName, FileExists(FileName)]));` and post a new log.

Comment: You try using `SaveStringToFile` to check if you can create the file.

Comment: Thank you. Now the easiest way is to directly try `SaveStringToFile`=> if this fails, the files must be opened somewhere (so you don't need to delete the file and don't need extra lines of code for FileExists) - this dummy file will be overwritten by the installer.

Comment: Yes, that's true.